# "Cannot resolve method" @AuthInterceptorOkHttpClient

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am trying to integrate dagger-hilt on my project on android. I have implemented the libraries and steps in the link below.
However, I cannot access the @AuthInterceptorOkHttpClient annotation. I get the error "Cannot resolve method". For this I need to add another library. Can experienced friends help?

https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?hl=ja_jp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthInterceptorOkHttpClient` is custome interface.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class AuthInterceptorOkHttpClient
```

They give an [example](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#multiple-bindings) in cases where you need Hilt to provide different implementations of the same type as dependencies.